# Android dialog setMultiChoiceItems /arraylist remove not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ArrayList<String> nameItems, selectedItems;
    ArrayList<Integer> numCheckedArray;
    TextView mTextView;
    Button mButton;
    String[] namesStringArray;
    boolean[] checkedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nameItems = new ArrayList();

        selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        numCheckedArray = new ArrayList<>();


        nameItems.add("Test 1");
        nameItems.add("Test 2");
        nameItems.add("Test 3");
        nameItems.add("Test 4");

        namesStringArray = new String[nameItems.size()];

        for (int i =0; i< nameItems.size(); i++){
            namesStringArray[i] = nameItems.get(i);
        }

        checkedItems = new boolean[nameItems.size()];



        mButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        mTextView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.testTextView);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select Your Items");
                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(namesStringArray, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {


                        if (isChecked){
                            //add the position that the user clicked on
                            numCheckedArray.add(which);


                        }else if (numCheckedArray.contains(which)) {
                            //remove the position that the user clicked on
                            numCheckedArray.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));

                        }
                    }
                });

                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                        //add selected items into selected item array      still need to figure out how to remove it from the array
                        for (int i = 0; i < numCheckedArray.size(); i++){

                            //if item is already in array and is still checked don't do anything
                            if (selectedItems.contains(nameItems.get(numCheckedArray.get(i))) && checkedItems[numCheckedArray.get(i)] == true){
                                Log.d("test", "do nothing is called");

                            }

                            //if item is already in array and is not checked remove from array
                            else if (selectedItems.contains(nameItems.get(numCheckedArray.get(i))) && checkedItems[numCheckedArray.get(i)] == false){
                                Log.d("test", "Remove is called");
                                selectedItems.remove(nameItems.get(numCheckedArray.get(i)));

                            }

                            //add item to array
                            else {
                                Log.d("test", "add is called");
                                selectedItems.add(nameItems.get(numCheckedArray.get(i)));
                            }
                        }



                        //used to see the values of the arrays

                        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++){
                            Log.d("test", String.valueOf(checkedItems[i]));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++){
                            Log.d("test", selectedItems.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
}
```

There are 3 goals that I want to accomplish with my program. They are:

- When an item is checked and is not in the selectedItems arraylist, add it to the arraylist when I click ok (This part is working fine).
- When an item is checked and is already in the selectedItems arraylist, do nothing when I click ok (This part also works fine).
- When an item is unchecked and is already in the selectedItems arraylist, remove it from the arraylist when I click ok (This part is not working and is driving me nuts).

My question is, why is the following lines of code never being called:

```
Log.d("test", "Remove is called");  
selectedItems.remove(nameItems.get(numCheckedArray.get(i)));
```

I do not understand why the logic is not working here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you **Remove** your unchecked items at the time  you uncheck them (even before you press ok)

in this block

```
else if (numCheckedArray.contains(which)) {
                                //remove the position that the user clicked on
                                numCheckedArray.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
```

so all the items are true when you check this `checkedItems[numCheckedArray.get(i)]` because you removed unchecked ones

If you want to execute `Log.d("test", "Remove is called");`   comment the else part `numCheckedArray.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));`

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem, but now how do I remove the unchecked positions from the numCheckArray? putting numCheckedArray.remove in the section that removes items from the selectedItems array seems to cause bugs.

Comment: @topgun741  if it solved your question you should accept it as answer first :P

Comment: Hehe cool.Now when do you add items to that array.If you do not add them then you do not need to remove them.If you add them when you check and hit ok and next time if you uncheck them then you can check the state after button click and remove that unchecked once

Comment: add and remove before user press OK is not the best way. let user to select when dialog appears..  do not make changes at that time.. but after user press ok you can always get the state .. then you can take action s. After hit ok loop and check what items are true what are false.refresh your list and add only true ones,then you will always have the check items in your list

Comment: @topgun741  what you need to understand is users always change their section before they confirm.So take data before any confirmation is not good.If you do that way you also need to reverse what you did if the user selects Cancel.I hope you understand it

Comment: yes, you advice helped me to figure it out and it works flawlessly! Thank you!

Comment: @topgun741 you are welcome ,,missed that upvote since you have 13 points sigh ;)